# Get File Name in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code in Tkinter that uploads 2 files and stores them in variables. I want it so that after each file is chosen, the path of the file is displayed on the Tkinter Window. With the current code, `print(file_path.name)`, prints the path however, it's not on the Tkinter Window but rather the console. How can I fix this to print the name in the window itself so that users can see when the run it?

```
ws = Tk()
ws.title('Uploading Files')
ws.geometry('400x200')
def open_file1():
    file_path = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('All Files', '*.tpi')])
    print(file_path.name)
    if file_path is not None:
        global file1
        file1 = file_path.read()
        

def open_file2():
    file_path = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('All Files', '*.tpi')])
    print(file_path.name)
    if file_path is not None:
        global file2
        file2 = file_path.read()        
        
content = []
content2 = []
def uploadFiles(data=None):
    global content
    content = file1
    global content2
    content2 = file2
    ws.destroy()   
    
first = Label(
    ws,
    text='Upload old File '
)
first.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)

firstbtn = Button(
    ws,
    text='Choose File',
    command=lambda: open_file1()
)
firstbtn.grid(row=0, column=1)

second = Label(
    ws,
    text='Upload new File '
)
second.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)

secondbtn = Button(
    ws,
    text='Choose File ',
    command=lambda: open_file2()
)
secondbtn.grid(row=1, column=1)

upld = Button(
    ws,
    text='Upload Files',
    command=uploadFiles
)
upld.grid(row=3, columnspan=3, pady=10)

ws.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You haven't updated any tkinter widget inside `open_file1()` and `open_file2()`, so why do you expect there is update in the tkinter window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update Label inside file dialog
`Label(ws, text=file_path.name).grid(row=0, column=10)`

```
def open_file1():
    file_path = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('All Files', '*.png')])  
    if file_path is not None:
        print(file_path.name)
        Label(ws, text=file_path.name).grid(row=0, column=10)
        global file1
        file1 = file_path.read()
```

this is output of code
[image: output of code]

I hope it will work for you

Comment: If `file_path` is `None`, you added code will raise exception.  Move your added code inside the if block.

Comment: Move the `print(...)` as well.

Comment: works perfect!!

Comment: I am glad to help you, thanks for Accepting the Answer and Upvoting @gcoder